# Что означает "Packages with upgradable origin but kept back"?

Tags: linux, debian

E-mail уведомление о unattended-upgrades:

```
Unattended upgrade returned: True
Packages that were upgraded:
Packages with upgradable origin but kept back:
linux-image-amd64
Unattended-upgrades log:
Initial blacklisted packages:
Initial whitelisted packages:
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename=stretch,label=Debian-Security']
Packages that will be upgraded:
```

Answer (score 1):

смысл скрипта *unattended-upgrades* — автоматически обновлять пакеты только из тех источников, которые явно разрешены.

в вашем случае разрешён один источник (так сделано по умолчанию, см. конф. файл `50unattended-upgrades` из пакета `unattended-upgrades`, который при установке пакета копируется в `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`):

```
Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename=stretch,label=Debian-Security']
```

а упомянутый в письме пакет `linux-image-amd64` (вообще-то мета-пакет, смысл которого лишь в установке указанных в нём зависимостей), вероятно, обновился в каком-то ином подключенном в вашей системе репозитории (не `debian-security` или не для выпуска `stretch`).

потому он не будет обновлён скриптом *unattended-upgrades*, о чём и написано в письме.

Comment: Проблема была в зависимостях https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-apt-get.en.html#s-upgrade

Comment: @MaximYaskov, это всё замечательно, но одно непонятно: где же тут «проблема»?